# My husband's been off sick with a broken leg, everyone had a pay rise except him. They said he can't have one, even though he's back at work

Tags: salary-review

My husband was off work 14 weeks with a broken leg, now he's back at work. In the meantime everyone has had a pay rise except for him, they said he wasn't there when they did pay review so he didn't get one. They said he needs to prove himself in order to get one, can they legally do this?

Comment: legal questions require us knowing the location. Please specify the country.

Comment: Your husband **was off work 14 weeks** that's practically three months at home for a broken leg.  My ex-husband once smashed his leg in  a motorcycle accident and was off work for months but he didn't lose any benefits.  In that space of time did your husband ever contacted his manager or colleagues?

Comment: "but he didn't lose any benefits" It seems the OP did neither. They just did not get the raise, other colleagues got in the meantime.

Comment: What does "prove himself" mean? And how is this different to what other staff would have done at the pay review?

Answer (score 9):

If your husband does not have some kind of contract that guarantees a pay raise (like his personal contract or maybe a union agreement covering his job) or the pay raise it automatic based on some scale (lets say he is paid according to his years of working there), or there are specific legal changes that make his current wage illegal (raising the minimum wage for example) then a pay raise is something to be negotiated.

There is no legal principle under which you are entitled to a raise in general.

You may have the right to have that salary review, since he missed it due to sick leave and most countries forbid discriminating based on certified sick leave. But there is no right to a favourable outcome if your husband *has* that review.

And let's be honest, "oh, I'm so sorry, you just missed it" is an excuse as lame as any. If they had wanted to give him a raise, there would have been a way. Assuming they don't do pay raises every quarter, missing fourteen weeks of work is no good reason to demand somebody "proves themselves", assuming that he worked there for a considerable time before (lets say a year or more). The only reason to "prove yourself" is if he wasn't on the job that long before and a quarter of a year is a considerable amount of their work experience there, or if the work itself changed dramatically over that time that he missed.

I know companies, that only have pay reviews and changes in their structure in specified intervals. One company I worked for only did it in January of each year and would string everybody along for months on end if job descriptions changed lets say in July. Certainly one of the reasons I said "worked", past tense. If a company needs me to take on more work, they need to pay me as soon as I do, not "next January, that's the rule, sorry".

This company is either over the top cheap, taking *any* excuse they can to not pay fair wages, or they do not want to pay your husband specifically more money. Either way, the way forward here is to take a deep breath and test the market, what *other* companies would pay. That is the only way to really know what would be a fair wage.

Comment: I suggest focusing on "OK, so what do I need to do/achieve in order to be given a comparable raise next time you do an evaluation"? It's easier to fix the future than the past.